# SQL: AVG with NULL Values

Tags: sql, oracle, null, average

As far as I understood, the AVG() function ignores NULL Values.

So AVG(4,4,4,4,4,NULL) --> 4

In my case I don't want this to happen.

I need a solution like that: AVG(4,4,4,4,4,NULL) --> 3,33

without replacing the NULL values directly in the table itself.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `NULL`s shouldn't be being used if the actual data should have been `0`s. `NULL`s and `0`s being "equivalent" is a C-ism that has no place in a database.

Comment: I know but i am afraid i have no influence on that in this case

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `coalesce()` to return the real value of zero for null columns:

```
select avg(coalesce(some_column, 0))
from ...
```

Comment: Lots of variants to this COALESCE syntax.  I like ISNULL() functions best (makes more sense linguistically).  More info: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Answer (score 4):

You are correct about the behavior of AVG - use [COALESCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) to convert the NULLs to 0 in the aggregate.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17513637/2864740) in "Why SUM(null) is not 0 in Oracle?"

> If you are looking for a rationale for this behaviour, then it is to be found in the ANSI SQL standards which dictate that aggregate operators ignore NULL values.

The relevant code is then, simply:

```
Avg(Coalesce(col,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coalesce` or `nvl` also.
Since `coalesce` examples are already given above, here is an example of `nvl`

```
Avg(Nvl(Column_Name),0)
```

Coalesce, Nvl, Nvl2 functions are handy in such cases of handling null values.
You should look up some examples and documentation on these.

Answer (score 0):

NVL, NVL2, or COALESCE could be used to solve this issue.

like this
select avg(4,4,4,4, nvl(null, 0 )) from dual;

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to calculate average using aggregate functions SUM with COUNT

```
SELECT SUM(column_with_value) / COUNT(primary_column) FROM ...
```